# Connecting SSMS to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm in a database class and I'm trying to just run a database that the instructor has already given us. He told us we need to have SSMS installed and showed us in a video, but when he opened SSMS, he could connect right away.

This is what I get when I open my SSMS. But when I try to type in local and then connect I get an error 53.

[image: Network error]

Can anyone help me please get this connected?

Comment: SSMS is a client application to manage Microsoft SQL Server. Did you install that database engine as well? They are separate installations. If you did, then what version did you install?

Comment: Check if the SQL Server Engine is running and the Firewall not blocking the default port (1433), also check if the TCP Protocol port is Enable.

Comment: @sander Yes, I installed it.

Comment: @mauriciokenny How do I check to make sure it's running?

Comment: @LaurenTownsend open Task Manager and find sqlservr.exe is up running. As you are new to this, better if you read more documentation and watch related videos about this RDBMS

Comment: @mauriciokenny its not there. I've used MySQL before, but not this, and I can't find any information on how to use this software. I've been trying. Hence why I am here asking

Comment: @LaurenTownsend You can start the SQL Server database engine under Start > Services, scroll down to SQL Server and start the service [just like the first option shown here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6307/how-to-stop-and-start-sql-server-services/). The rest of that page and [this page in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/start-stop-pause-resume-restart-sql-server-services) also list some alternatives.